# PHP MySQL Display One Time

Tags: php

I have two tables called categories and topics.

categories has columns category_id and category_title. topics has columns topic_id, topic_title, and category_id.

I currently display the columns like so:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, 'SELECT c.category_title, t.topic_title FROM categories c JOIN topics t on c.category_id = t.category_id');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$category_title[] = $row['category_title'];
$topic_title[] = $row['topic_title'];
}

<?php

foreach ($category_title as $category_title): 

echo htmlspecialchars($category_title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?><br />

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php

foreach ($topic_title as $topic_title): 

echo htmlspecialchars($topic_title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?><br />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will display as:

Category 1
Category 1
Category 2

Topic 1
Topic 2
Topic 3

Topic 1 and 2 are assigned to Category 1, while Topic 3 is assign to Category 2.

How can I have Category display once if there are multiple topics assign to it, such as:

Category 1
Category 2

Topic 1
Topic 2
Topic 3

Please no classes and objects examples. I'm not learning that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run query two time first for category then run new query to selected topic according to category as below:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, 'SELECT c.category_id,c.category_title FROM categories as c');
    $recordArray=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $category_id = $row['category_id'];
    $recordArray[$category_id] = $row['category_title'];
    //Query For Topic
    $getTopic = mysqli_query($db_server, "SELECT t.topic_title FROM topics as t WHERE t.category_id='".$category_id."'");
    while ($getRow = mysqli_fetch_array($getTopic))
    {
        $recordArray[$category_id]['topic'][] = $getRow['topic_title']; 
    }

}
print"<pre>";
print_r($recordArray);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the closest to what I am looking for. I just had to change it where it doesn't use print_r to print an array. I just wanted to echo cateory_title and topic_title;

Answer (score 0):

Use group_concat, here is an example  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your SQL query adding a "GROUP BY" statement. It would be something like:

```
SELECT c.category_title, t.topic_title FROM categories c JOIN topics t on c.category_id = t.category_id GROUP BY c.category_id
```

You can find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) a clear example of using GROUP BY.

Comment: GROUP BY makes the Topics display once as well. So I get the results: Category 1 Category 2

Topic 1 Topic 3

Comment: @markerpower Oh, sorry, you're right. :) Glad you found your solution however ;)

Answer (score 0):

written off my head not tested:
first I dunno why don't you use it inside one loop, it will perform faster but it will swap the output

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, 'SELECT c.category_title, t.topic_title FROM categories c JOIN topics t on c.category_id = t.category_id');
$oldCategory='';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($oldCategory!=$row['category_title']) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['category_title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'<br />';
        $oldCategory=$row['category_title'];
        }
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['topic_title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'<br />';
    }
```

or this will not swap the output:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, 'SELECT c.category_title, t.topic_title FROM categories c JOIN topics t on c.category_id = t.category_id');
$oldCategory='';
$catStr='';
$topStr='';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($oldCategory!=$row['category_title']) {
        $catStr.=htmlspecialchars($row['category_title'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8').'<br />';
        $oldCategory=$row['category_title'];
        }
    $topStr.=htmlspecialchars($row['topic_title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'<br />';
    }
echo $catStr.$topStr;
```

Comment: Before I posted this topic, I came across examples like these and for some reason I still get the same problem where the same Category displays multiple times.